# Monit : Add username and password for mysql check

Tags: mysql, monit

I have a "problem" with my Monit configuration.
The monitoring works as expected, but I get the following errors on the mysql error file `/var/log/mysql/error.log` each time the monitoring script runs :

```
190821 10:47:49 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
190821 10:48:19 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
190821 10:48:49 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
190821 10:49:19 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
190821 10:49:49 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Here is my monit config file :

```
 check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
   group database
   group mysql
   start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
   stop  program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
   if failed host localhost port 3306 protocol mysql then alert
   depend mysql_bin
   depend mysql_rc

 check file mysql_bin with path /usr/sbin/mysqld
   group mysql
   include /etc/monit/templates/rootbin

 check file mysql_rc with path /etc/init.d/mysql
   group mysql
   include /etc/monit/templates/rootbin
```

Is there a way to specify a username and password for the monit checks to prevent those warnings on the error log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is monit trying to connect to your MySQL instance as an anonymous user.
Either you create an anonymous user (not recommended), or per the [official documentation](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#MYSQL):

> **MYSQL**
>
> Syntax:
>
> `PROTOCOL MYSQL [USERNAME string PASSWORD string]`
>
> *USERNAME* MySQL
>   username (maximum 16 characters).
>
> *PASSWORD* MySQL password (special characters can be used, but for
>   non-alphanumerics the password has to be quoted).
>
> Username and password (credentials) are **optional** and if not set, Monit
>   will perform the test using anonymous login. This can cause an
>   authentication error to be logged in your MySQL log, depending on your
>   MySQL configuration.
>
> If credentials are set, Monit will login and perform a MySQL ping
>   test. Monit does not require any database privileges, it just needs
>   the database user. You might want to create standalone user for Monit
>   to use when testing, for example:
>
> ```
> CREATE USER 'monit'@'host_from_which_monit_performs_testing'
> IDENTIFIED BY 'mysecretpassword';  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> check process mysql with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
>      start program = "/sbin/start mysql"
>      stop program = "/sbin/stop mysql"
>      if failed
>         port 3306
>         protocol mysql username "foo" password "bar"
>      then alert
> ```

Comment: It's working, thank you !
I'd tried this solution before, but it didn't work.
What worked this time : username and password between double quotes !